# Passing a JSON Object from R to Javascript

Tags: javascript, r, json, d3.js, circle-pack

I am trying to send data from R to JavaScript and in R I have a I am converting the contents I have to JSON format using the below mentioned code:

```
data = jsonlite::toJSON(data, pretty=TRUE,flatten=TRUE,auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

I am assigning a div id for the variable `data` in R and doing a DOM in JavaScript to get the contents of the variable `data` in JavaScript.

Please find below JavaScript Code:

```
var data = document.getElementById("data").innerHTML;
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
alert(myJSON);

function flareData(){
return myJSON;
}
```

However, if I hardcode the contents of `myJSON` after return in `flaredata()` then it would work as expected. But I am not able to return it using a variable.

I am able to alert the contents in JavaScript but I am not able to pass it as an input to another funtion named `flaredata` which will generate CirclepackeR(graphs).

Am I missing any conversions in JavaScript or R?

Comment: Can you also show js code? Since it's hard to answer with only JSON

Comment: Updated the Js code, apologies for not doing it at first place.

Comment: So, you are saying, that calling flareData() and not getting JSON?

Comment: Yes, I can alert it in JS though. Also if I manually paste the contents of myJSON inside the flaredata function it works perfectly fine.